# Is there any way to use the same code for both a class method and an instance method?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to use the same code for both a Class method and an instance method?

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
Module MyModule

  def method_in_module
    puts "hello"
  end

  class SomeClass       
    def some_method
      method_in_module
    end
  end
end
```

and then I would like to be able to do this:

```
SomeClass.method_in_module
```

or this

```
a = SomeClass.new
a.method_in_module
```

I think I can have two methods, a `self.class_method_in_module` and `instance_method_in_module` and then include them in the class, (in my real example classes),  but the code would be identical.

Comment: `almost identical` is an important keyword. What are the differences?

Comment: the code would be identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Module.included` hook to extend the class with the module.

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend MyModule
  end

  def method_in_module
    puts "foo"
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include MyModule
end

SomeClass.new.method_in_module
# => foo
SomeClass.method_in_module
# => foo
```

It's important to keep in mind that class and instance have different scopes. So a method that works well in the class scope, may not work very well in the class scope.

Ideally, I would suggest to define the methods at class-level and from the instance level call the class-level method.

Generally speaking, I don't see where the pattern of creating the same method at both class-level and instance-level makes sense. It can make sense occasionally, but avoid generating a large number of duplicated methods.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to have a class method also available on instances. E.g. when you can set global configuration settings on the (singleton) class which you then want to make available more easily on the instances, i.e. to avoid the `self.class.my_class_method` pattern.

Comment: @HolgerJust I agree, that's why I wrote `It can make sense occasionally` ;) But it's important to not abuse it.

Comment: It makes sense when then method is really just a function and you don't want to pollute `Kernel` to make it pretend to be a function.

Comment: I was going to be using this as part of a delegation/method-rename scheme.  So the real method would take a target method name and some arguments, do a little bit of logic and then call the target method.  I was looking into Forwardable, but I like the idea of maybe using rdoc to document the classes and my understanding is that that would not work.  I will try out this solution - thanks

Comment: Simone, this implies that every class that includes `MyModule` wants the class `extend`ed as well.  Why did you suggest this rather than just adding `extend MyModule` to the class definition?

Comment: @CarySwoveland There was no different requirement in the question, thus I took that way. However, that's a fair point.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to implement this. One way would be to pull the class out of the module and then to include / extend module into the class

```
module MyModule
  def method_in_module
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include MyModule # adds the methods to class instances
  extend MyModule # Adds the methods to the class
end
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [Forwardable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module in Ruby which allows you to forward methods to other objects.

```
require 'forwardable'

module MyModule
  def self.method_in_module
    puts "hello"
  end

  class SomeClass
    extend Forwardable

    def_delegator :MyModule, :method_in_module

    def self.method_in_module(*args, &block)
      MyModule.method_in_module(*args, &block)
    end

    def some_method
      method_in_module
    end
  end
end
```

If you are in a Rails context (i.e. with ActiveSupport), you can also use the [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method which works similar to the Forwardable variant above.

Note that both these variants are only usable to create instance methods. For class methods, you still have to define the method on your own as shown in the `Forwardable` example above.

Comment: RE #1, to make the methods of `MyModule` available to only a single instance of `SomeClass`, `a = SomeClass.new; a.extend MyModule`.  Perhaps worth noting that `include` and `extend` can be invoked outside the class def: `Someclass.extend MyModule; Someclass.include MyModule`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `include` is a private method which can only be invoked from the outside by overriding the normal scope as `SomeClass.send(:include, MyModule)`.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight.  I knew it was OK for `extend` so didn't bother to check for `include`.  There's a lesson there.